# Failed to update SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM to SP3

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, service-pack

I'm trying to update SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM to SP3 by running `SQLServer2008R2SP3-KB2979597-x64-ENU.exe`, on Windowns Server 2008 R2 SP1.

It failed with the following error in the log,

> 2015-11-26 10:24:01 SQLEngine: : Version-copying file from 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' to 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll'.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 SQLEngine: : Failed to version-copy file 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Install\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' to 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll'. Exception data is: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' is denied.
>   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.Globals.VersionCopy(ServiceContainer context, String source, String target).
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Access to the path 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' is denied.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: The configuration failure category of current exception is ConfigurationFailure
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Configuration action failed for feature SQL_Engine_Core_Inst during timing ConfigRC and scenario ConfigRC.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' is denied.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.Globals.VersionCopy(ServiceContainer context, String source, String target)
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp:
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Patch_ConfigRC(EffectiveProperties properties)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlEngine.SqlEngineSetupPrivate.Patch(ConfigActionTiming timing, Dictionary`2 actionData, PublicConfigurationBase spcb)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.ExecuteAction(String actionId)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlConfigBase.SlpConfigAction.Execute(String actionId, TextWriter errorStream)
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Source: Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SqlServer_ConfigExtension.
>   2015-11-26 10:24:01 Slp: Message: Access to the path 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\sqlscriptdowngrade.dll' is denied..

I get the exact same error every time I run setup and even after rebooting.

I checked the path `d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\` it's owned by `SYSTEM`, and regardless of whether I ran the setup as admin, in TaskManager it's still showing that `setup100.exe` is running under by account. I tried and can't rename the file, unless if I take over the ownership of the folder, though I worried that doing so will break SQL Server.

Any idea what went wrong?

EDIT: I've compared the same folder on another DB server with the same installation (not scheduled to update SP3 yet), I can rename the `sqlscriptdowngrade.dll` file after an admin prompt. The permission for the folder is the same for both machine.

Comment: When you say `run the setup as admin` are you referring to an admin account or running it under the `run as administrator` context from the right-click menu?

Comment: Context menu - Run as administrator. I'm the domain admin as well.

Comment: Even if you are domain admin did you made sure the this domain account is added as Local admin on machine where you are running SP3 update. Did you manually tried giving full permission to the folder location `d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn`

Comment: Domain admin is already added to local Administrators group. Also, I can't change the folder permission without first taking over the ownership. Since I can't find any similar issue resolved by taking over ownership, I'll keep that as last resort.

Comment: Can you share the complete logs on a shared location like Onedrive, dropbox and add the link in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a SQL update in Windows Update pulled from our WSUS server, [Security update for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3045316) and not realizing that it's an cumulative update, it managed to update the SQL server to 10.50.6220 (SP3 = 10.50.6000) without any error. I'm guessing probably some issue with the original SP3 setup. I'll update here again if I face any issue when we schedule to update the other SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is an open issue like this, in [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/802143/failure-to-upgrade-from-sql2012-sp1-cu3-to-cu6-on-alwayson-cluster) that may have been resolved on 2008 in later updates. maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Thanks, hmm, wonder why this didn't show up when googling. Anyway, there's no solution being mentioned and the bug is still active, lol

Comment: yeah, that's true. ;)